# String to now() MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to convert string to date? I have below date.

```
'012018'
```

Which I want to convert to MySQL `now()`. It should be like this

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

I am storing value in this format.

Comment: `012018` looks like a month and year only. Does that mean other than the month and year, the day and timestamp value would all be default to 1 (day) and zero (timestamp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is two digit month, day, and year:

```
select TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('012018','%m%d%y'));
```

If it is two digit month and four digit year:

```
select TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01','012018'),'%d%m%Y'));
```

Comment: A MySQL date by default will be sitting at midnight (IIRC).  So, wrapping in `TIMESTAMP` might be unnecessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes.  it just wasn't clear to me if they meant they are providing the 012018 string to store into a timestamp column or they have 012018 stored in a character-type column and want to select a timestamp-looking format